# How to Reverse a linked list using recursion in object oriented programming with c++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program in c++ that reverse a linked list in c++.
And I have seen a lot of questions about it but my answer is not on them so please don't mark this as a duplicate!

I want to reverse a linked list using recursion and this is my full program and on Function reverse recursion() there is something wrong with it those programs ends and don't print.

I have tried to Get this function out of my class but it doesn't work and I have tried to make the head global too.

```
class LinkedList{
public:
    Node* Head;
    int Length;
    LinkedList(Node* head,int c){
        Head=head;
        Length=c;
    }
    void ReverseRecursion(Node* temp,Node** Heading){
        if(temp->next==0){
            *Heading = temp;
            cout << "This is the head item==>" << temp->value << " And this 
            is the Heading now " << *Heading << endl;
            return;
        }
        ReverseRecursion(temp,Heading);
        temp->next->next = temp;
        temp->next = 0;
    }
}
```

I have insert and delete and print functions in this class But i have test them and they are correct.

And on my main, I save the head element in a local variable on main and every time I pass it to the LinkedList.

And I call this function like this on main :

```
MyLinked.ReverseRecursion(head,&head);
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code under a debugger? If you think carefully about the value of temp when you call `ReverseRecursion` you might see what your error is. Hint your program is probably ending due to a stack overflow.

Comment: You're always passing the same value in `temp`, so unless your list only has one element the function will never return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the recursion function you must pass a different parameter, otherwise you will have an infinite recursion until you get out of memory.

Try this version, where each time you call the function with the next element in the list, until you find the end of the list:

```
class LinkedList{
public:
    Node* Head;
    int Length;
    LinkedList(Node* head,int c){
        Head=head;
        Length=c;
    }
    void ReverseRecursion(Node* temp,Node** Heading){
        if(temp->next==0){
            *Heading = temp;
            cout << "This is the head item==>" << temp->value << " And this 
            is the Heading now " << *Heading << endl;
            return;
        }
        ReverseRecursion(temp->next,Heading);
        temp->next->next = temp;
        temp->next = 0;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I show a complete testing of how my solution works. I intended to do the minimum change necessary to the original code to make it work, and the minimum is changing only one word:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
  public:
    int value;
    Node * next;

    Node(int v, Node * n) : value(v), next(n) {}
};

class LinkedList{
public:
    Node* Head;
    int Length;
    LinkedList(Node* head,int c){
        Head=head;
        Length=c;
    }
    void ReverseRecursion(Node* temp,Node** Heading){
        if(temp->next==0){
            *Heading = temp;
            //cout << "This is the head item==>" << temp->value << " And this
            //is the Heading now " << *Heading << endl;
            return;
        }
        ReverseRecursion(temp->next,Heading);
        temp->next->next = temp;
        temp->next = 0;
    }
    void print() const;
};


void LinkedList::print() const {
  cout << '{';

  for (Node* node = Head; node != 0; node = node->next)
    cout << ' ' << node->value; // value is public ?

  cout << " }" << endl;
}


int main()
{
  Node n3(3, 0);
  Node n2(2, &n3);
  Node n1(1, &n2);
  LinkedList ll(&n1, 3);
  Node *heading;

  ll.print();
  ll.ReverseRecursion(&n1, &heading);
  ll.Head = heading;
  ll.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
{ 1 2 3 }
{ 3 2 1 }
```

Comment: Each node has its next set by the previous node, in recursive fashion. The first original node will become the last node and have its next set to 0 and not replaced by any other node.

Comment: I've edited my code to add the full test code to show how it works.

Comment: Hi @bruno, I see you've removed the comment saying my code did not work, it was not necessary to remove it. But it would be nice instead if you would also remove the negative vote on my answer. Thanks!